# enviar petición post a server mediante fetch

Tags: javascript, php

Lo que intento es crear el objeto, lo inserto al arreglo para después usar `fetch` y `json.strinfy` y hacer el envío al server, lo descifro usando `json_decode`, y antes de poder recorrerlo me sale este error:

> VM247:1 Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'a', "array(1) {"... is not valid JSON

```js
var pasarDatos=[]
const newItem = {
    id: idcap,
    codigo: codigocap,
    nombre: nombrecap,
};

pasarDatos.push(newItem)

fetch('./php.php', {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
       'Accept': 'application/json',
       'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({pasarDatos})
        .then(function(data){return data.json();})
        .then(myJson => { console.log(myJson);});
```

Devuelve como resultado este array

```php
         array(1) {
           ["pasarDatos"]=>
            array(1) {
               [0]=>
               array(8) {
               ["id"]=>
              string(2) "15"
             ["codigo"]=>
             string(5) "00001"
             ["nombre"]=>
             string(12) "  Nike force"            
            }
         }
      }
```

En mi script tengo esto

```php
$datos = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'),true);
var_dump($datos);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El mensaje de error indica que lo que se recibe no es un objeto JSON válido debido a que nunca se llega a recibir el JSON sino un *array*... un *array* de objetos. El método `JSON.stringify()` no genera un JSON del *array* de objetos; tan solo produce un *array* con los objetos internos *parseados* al formato JSON.

Esto es lo que se consigna en la documentación ofrecida [aquí](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify):

> Arrays are serialized as arrays (enclosed by square brackets). Only array indices between 0 and length - 1 (inclusive) are serialized; other properties are ignored.

Para recibir un JSON válido y decodificarlo con la función `json_decode()` de PHP, tendrías que enviar una cadena de caracteres de la forma `'{"atributo":"valor"}'`, a la cual, con JavaScript, previamente *parseaste* con el método `JSON.stringify()`.

Algo así:

```
const json = JSON.stringify('{"atributo":"valor"}');
fetch(`destino.php?json=${json}`) //O si lo prefieres así: fetch("destino.php?json=" + json)
```

```
<?php
echo json_decode($_GET['json']); //{"atributo":"valor"}
?>
```

Ahora bien. Si lo que deseas es enviar varios objetos, razón por la cual recurres al uso de un *array*, pienso que te convendría apoyarte en el objeto `FormData()`. Solo tendrías que recorrer el conjunto de pares atributo-valor de cada objeto y, en la parte en donde se indica el índice de la variable del método `append()`, añadir unos *brackets* (`[]`) para que se forme un *array* de cada atributo.

Más o menos así:

```
let obj, arr = [], data = new FormData();

//Primer objeto
obj = {
    nombre: "Elena",
    edad: 29
};

arr.push(obj);

//Segundo objeto
obj = {
    nombre: "Ignacio",
    edad: 37
};

arr.push(obj);

//Y así, sucesivamente...

arr.forEach(o => {
    data.append("nombre[]", o.nombre);
    data.append("edad[]", o.edad);
});

fetch("destino.php", {
    method: "POST",
    body: data
})
.then(response => response.text())
.then(texto => console.log(texto));
```

Y con PHP se puede visualizar los datos recorriendo ambos *arrays* en un solo bucle:

```
<?php
for ($i = 0, $length = count($_POST['nombre']); $i < $length; $i++){
    echo nl2br("Nombre: {$_POST['nombre'][$i]} - Edad: {$_POST['edad'][$i]}\n");
}
?>
```

El resultado sería así:

```
Nombre: Elena - Edad: 29
Nombre: Ignacio - Edad: 37
```

Un saludo

Comment: Gracias alexis88