# Error al enviar datos en un array javascript mediante ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Tengo este codigo, y todo parece funcionar correctamente pero al enviar el ajax me da un error y no entiendo porque. El array está bien y los contenidos son los extraidos tanto de un textarea como de un formulario sin embargo siembre me muestra el alert del error.
Este es el codigo de que enviar el array

```
$.ajax({
            
                url: '../acciones/acciones.php?option=NA',
                type: 'post',
                data: datos,
                dataType: 'json',
                success : function (response) {
                    console.log();
                var len = response.length;

                    alert ("Artículo: "+num_articulo+" "+nombre_articulo+"\n"+parrafoparaintroducir);
                    alert("enviado");
                },                      
                error : function(error){
                    
                    alert("error al enviar");
                }
                });
```

Luego el php acciones recoge el get y según su valor inserta los valores en la BD.

```
$r_option = $_GET['option']; //Capturamos la opcion para los casos desde la URL
switch($r_option)
{
case "NA":

//NUEVOS ARTICULOS DESDE EL TEXTAREA
                $r_num_articulo = $_POST['num_articulo'];
                $r_nombre_articulo = $_POST['nombre_articulo'];
                $r_contenido_articulo = $_POST['contenido_articulo'];
    
                $r_idley = $_POST['id_ley'];
                $r_idtitulo = $_POST['id_titulo'];
                $r_idcapitulo = $_POST['id_capitulo'];
                //$r_idseccion = $_POST['id_seccion'];
                //$r_idsubseccion = $_POST['id_subseccion'];                
                

        $sql="INSERT INTO articulos (num_articulo, nombre_articulo, contenido_articulo, id_ley, id_titulo, id_capitulo, id_seccion, id_subseccion) VALUES (
                 '".$r_num_articulo."',
                 '".$r_nombre_articulo."',
                 '".$r_contenido_articulo."',
                 '".$r_idley."',
                 '".$r_idtitulo."',
                 '".$r_idcapitulo."',
                 '".$r_idseccion."'),
                 '".$r_idsubseccion."')";
                 $res=mysqli_query($con,$sql);
                 echo "<script>window.location.href=\"../nuevos/nuevo_articulo.php?idseccion=".$r_idseccion."\";</script>";
    break;;
}
```

¿Que es lo que puede estar ocurriendo?

EDITO: He modificado el ajax y el php con lo siguiente: (uso un array de clave/valor con varios elementos)

```
var jsonData = JSON.stringify(datos);
        
    $.ajax({
                url: '../acciones/grabar_articulos.php',
                type: 'post',
                data: {data: jsonData},
                dataType: 'json',
                success : function(response) {
                console.log(response);
                },                      
                error : function(error){
                alert("error al enviar");
                }
                });
```

el PHP es este:

```
$data = json_decode($_POST['data'], true);
$contador = count($data);

include "../config.php";

for ($i = 0; $i < $contador; $i++) {
$num_articulo = $data[$i]['num_articulo'];
$nombre_articulo = $data[$i]['nombre_articulo'];
$contenido_articulo = $data[$i]['contenido_articulo'];
$id_ley = $data[$i]['id_ley'];
$id_titulo = $data[$i]['id_titulo'];
$id_capitulo = $data[$i]['id_capitulo'];
$id_seccion = $data[$i]['id_seccion'];
$id_subseccion = $data[$i]['id_subseccion'];

$sql = "INSERT INTO articulos (
            num_articulo,
            nombre_articulo,
            contenido_articulo,
            id_ley,
            id_titulo,
            id_capitulo,
            id_seccion,
            id_subseccion
        )
        VALUES (
            '$num_articulo',
            '$nombre_articulo',
            '$contenido_articulo',
            '$id_ley',
            '$id_titulo',
            '$id_capitulo',
            '$id_seccion',
            '$id_subseccion'
        )";

$res = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
}
```

Ahora, me muestra el alert de "error al enviar" al ejecutarse el ajax. El error del servidor es 500, no especifica nada más, sin embargo, después de muchas pruebas, al introducir un un registro con phpmyadmin en la tabla a la que quiero ingresar los datos ha ocurrido algo extraño. Tenia varios registros metidos a mano, donde el id_articulo es  un autoincremental y primary key, pues bien tenia varios articulos con el id 1, 2 ,3 ,4....pero despues de muchas pruebas, y al meter otro registro con phpmyadmin, el id a dado un salto a 34.
Me va a estallar la cabeza :P

Comment: me da un error 500 en el servidor...sigo investigando

Comment: Hola, ¿qué dice exactamente el mensaje de error? Pulsa en [edit] y agrégalo como texto a la pregunta. Quizá sea que tienes un punto y coma de más aquí: `break;;`, debería ser: **`break;`** Por otra parte, parece que no has entendido del todo cómo funciona Ajax. Poner un `window.location` desde el servidor no tiene ningún sentido en este contexto, devuelve la respuesta a Ajax y desde allí haz la redirección si es que fuera necesario (no suele serlo cuando usas Ajax). Si necesitas más cosas del servidor, búscalas directamente. Tu código es bastante confuso en ese punto.

Comment: Gracias por comentar A. Cedano, la verdad es que soy novato en esto. El servidor no reporta nada concreto solo error 500.

Comment: ¿Corregiste el error de duplicidad del `;` y el problema persiste? Considera revisar el log de errores para tener mayores detalles del error.

Comment: Opte por enviarlo a otro archivo php con unicamente el codigo necesario. Gracias por tu interés

Answer (score 1):

Es muy probable que estés teniendo un problema con los datos enviados dado que, en el lado del servidor, esperas recibir un JSON, pero quizá solo estés recibiendo un arreglo. [Un caso similar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/595130/enviar-petici%C3%B3n-post-a-server-mediante-fetch/595154#595154) fue publicado por aquí no hace mucho. Puedes probar con la solución sugerida en esa publicación.

Otra cosa a tomar en cuenta es que el atributo `dataType` sirve para indicar el tipo de respuesta que se espera del servidor, no el tipo de datos que se está enviando. Aunque, claro, en ese caso el error se daría en el lado del cliente, pero no deja de ser algo que haya que corregir.

Realiza los cambios y nos avisas cómo te fue.

Un saludo

---

**EDICIÓN 1:** En aras de que se entienda mejor el uso del objeto `FormData` para este caso, lo explicaré con un ejemplo.

Según entiendo, en un momento puedes llegar a tener un arreglo con la siguiente composición:

```javascript
[
    {
        name: "John",
        lastName: "Doe",
        age: 35
    },

    {
        name: "Henry",
        lastName: "Rearden",
        age: 42
    },

    //...
]
```

¿Cómo se puede integrar todo el contenido del arreglo en un objeto `FormData`?: Recorre el arreglo y añade cada par índice-valor adjuntando unos *brackets* (`[]`) a la derecha del índice para indicar que se trata de un arreglo de valores.

Sería más o menos así:

```javascript
let myData = new FormData();

myArray.forEach(object => {
    for (let key in object){
        myData.append(`${key}[]`, object[key]);
    }
});
```

Lo anterior generará un objeto `FormData` con todos los datos contenidos en cada uno de los objetos que constituyen el arreglo.

Finalmente, solo bastaría con que en la propiedad `data` del método `$.ajax()` establezcas el objeto `FormData` y lo envíes; mientras que, del lado del servidor, ya no haría falta que decodifiques nada. Bastaría con que accedas a cada valor de la forma `$_POST['indice'][$i]` dentro de la estructura `for`.

---

**EDICIÓN 2:** El error que indica el mensaje en la consola se debe a que el método `$.ajax()` requiere de dos propiedades extra para enviar datos mediante un objeto `FormData`, que son `processData` y `contentType`, ambos con el valor *booleano* `false` y que, por cierto, veo que los tienes comentados en el código.

Con los cambios necesarios, el bloque de la petición asíncrona quedaría así:

```javascript
$.ajax({
    url: '../acciones/grabar_articulos.php',
    type: 'post',
    data: data,
    processData: false,
    contentType: false,
    success: function(response) {
        console.log(response);
    },
    error: function(error){
        console.log("Error al enviar la solicitud ajax");
    }
});
```

Con esto tendría que bastar para que los datos sean enviados. Prueba y nos cuentas cómo te fue.

Comment: Funciona!!! por fin. Muchisimas gracias Alexis, un abrazo!

Comment: De nada, estimado. Un saludo.

Answer (score 0):

Gracias Alexis88 por responder, estoy usando este codigo para crear el array
Tengo las variables, num_articulo, nombre_articulo y parrafoparain

```
            datos = [{
                          num_articulo: num_articulo,
                          nombre_articulo: nombre_articulo,
                          contenido_articulo: parrafoparaintroducir,
                          id_ley: leyid,
                          id_titulo: tituloid,
                          id_capitulo: capituloid,
                          id_seccion: seccionid,
                          id_subseccion: subseccionid
                        }];
```

Luego voy añadiendo mediante push otros objetos con la misma estructura.
cuando muestro los contenidos en la consola de Firefox usando console.log (datos[0]) me muestra lo siguiente:

```
Object { num_articulo: "4", nombre_articulo: "Concepto de interesado.", contenido_articulo: "1. Se consideran interesados en el procedimiento administrativo:\n\n.....", id_ley: "1", id_titulo: "2", id_capitulo: "1", id_seccion: " ", id_subseccion: " " }
```

¿Estoy generando el array correctamente?

Comment: Te sugiero considerar la opción de usar un objeto `FormData`. En la publicación que adjunté hay un ejemplo.

Comment: ok, me pongo con ello.

Answer (score 0):

Despues de los cambios que propone Alexis, el codigo queda así. Pongo toda la función (consiste en capturar un textarea que se compone de varios articulos legales) y la captura de valores de un formulario.

```js
//FUNCION EXTRAER ARTICULOS TEXTAREA
        function myFunction() {             
        var texto = document.getElementById("textarea").value;//Capturamos el textarea
        var leyid = document.getElementById("id_ley_form2").value;
        var tituloid = document.getElementById("id_titulo_form2").value;
        var capituloid = document.getElementById("id_capitulo_form2").value;
        var seccionid = document.getElementById("id_seccion_form2").value;
        var subseccionid = document.getElementById("id_subseccion_form2").value;    
        var longitud = texto.length; //Averiguamos longitud del texto
    
        //SEPARAMOS EL TEXTO POR PARRAFOS Y AVERIGUAMOS Nº ARTICULO Y TITULO
        texto = texto.replace('\n\n','\n');
        var parrafo = texto.split ("\n"); //extraemos los parrafos
        var cantidaddeparrafos = parrafo.length; //contamos los parrafos
        //alert("Cantidad de parrafos: "+cantidaddeparrafos);
        var parrafoparaintroducir = "";
        var i=0;//contador de array
        var c=1;//contador numero de parrafos
        let datos = 0,  data = new FormData();
        while(c <= cantidaddeparrafos) {//Buscamos por cada Parrafo
            
            if (parrafo[i].startsWith('Artículo ') == true){// Si el parrafo empieza con Artículo

                var palabrasparrafo = parrafo[i].split(" ");
                var numeroarticulo = palabrasparrafo[1];//Capturamos el nº de articulo
                if (numeroarticulo.charAt(numeroarticulo.length - 1) == "." ){//Si termina en punto, lo eliminamos
                    numeroarticulo = numeroarticulo.substr(0, numeroarticulo.length - 1);
                    //alert ("El numero del articulo es: "+numeroarticulo); 
                    }else{//Si no termina en punto lo dejamos como está
                    //alert ("El numero del articulo es: "+numeroarticulo);
                    }

                if  (palabrasparrafo[2] != null){ //Averiguamos si el articulo tiene titulo
                var tituloarticulo = palabrasparrafo.slice(2).join(" ");
                //alert ("El titulo del articulo es: "+tituloarticulo);
                }else{
                var tituloarticulo = "ninguno"; 
                //alert ("El artículo no tiene título");
                }   
                parrafoparaintroducir = "";
                i++;
                c++;
            }else{

                while (parrafo[i].startsWith('Artículo') == false){//Unimos los parrafos que no empiezan por Artículo
                    if (parrafoparaintroducir ==""){    
                    parrafoparaintroducir = parrafo[i]; 
                    }else{
                    parrafoparaintroducir = parrafoparaintroducir+"\n"+parrafo[i];  
                    }
                
                i++;
                c++;
                    if(parrafo[i]==null){
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
            
        if (numeroarticulo!= ""){
            var num_articulo = numeroarticulo;      
        }
        if (tituloarticulo!=""){
            var nombre_articulo = tituloarticulo;

        }   
        if (num_articulo != null && nombre_articulo != null && parrafoparaintroducir !=="")
        {
            
                if (datos == 0){
                datos = [{
                              num_articulo: num_articulo,
                              nombre_articulo: nombre_articulo,
                              contenido_articulo: parrafoparaintroducir,
                              id_ley: leyid,
                              id_titulo: tituloid,
                              id_capitulo: capituloid,
                              id_seccion: seccionid,
                              id_subseccion: subseccionid
                            }];
                console.log("entra en el if datos = 0");
            }else{
                
                datos.push({
                    num_articulo: num_articulo,
                    nombre_articulo: nombre_articulo,
                    contenido_articulo: parrafoparaintroducir,
                    id_ley: leyid,
                    id_titulo: tituloid,
                    id_capitulo: capituloid,
                    id_seccion: seccionid,
                    id_subseccion: subseccionid
                            });
                console.log ("entra en el if datos else");
                }
                
        }
            
        }//Fin del primer While

        
        datos.forEach(object => {
                for (let key in object){
                    data.append(`${key}[]`, object[key]);
                }
            });
        
            
        for (const entry of data.entries()) {
        console.log(entry);};
            
        $.ajax({
                    url: '../acciones/grabar_articulos.php',
                    type: 'post',
                    data: data,
                    //processData: false,
                    //contentType: false,
                    //dataType: 'json',
                    success : function(response) {
                    console.log(response);
                    },                      
                    error : function(error){
                    console.log("Error al enviar la solicitud ajax");
                    }
                    });
            
    }//fin de la funcion
```

```html
<form id="form2" name="form2" method="post"  enctype="multipart/form-data" action="">
<input id="id_subseccion_form2" name="id_subseccion_form2" type="hidden" value=" ">
        <input id="id_seccion_form2" name="id_seccion_form2" type="hidden" value=" ">
        <input id="id_capitulo_form2" name="id_capitulo_form2" type="hidden" value=" ">
        <input id="id_titulo_form2" name="id_titulo_form2" type="hidden" value="1">
        <input id="id_ley_form2" name="id_ley_form2" type="hidden" value="1">
<textarea class="form-control" placeholder="Leave a comment here" id="textarea" style="height: 100px"></textarea>
        <button onclick="myFunction()">Obtener caracteres</button>
        <input name="racksI" type="hidden" id="lineas" class="form-control">
</form>
```

El php es:

```
<?php 
include "../config.php";

for ($i = 0, $length = count($_POST['num_articulo']); $i < $length; $i++){
$num_articulo = $_POST['num_articulo'][$i];
$nombre_articulo = $_POST['nombre_articulo'][$i];
$contenido_articulo = $_POST['contenido_articulo'][$i];
$id_ley = $_POST['id_ley'][$i];
$id_titulo = $_POST['id_titulo'][$i];
$id_capitulo = $_POST['id_capitulo'][$i];
$id_seccion = $_POST['id_seccion'][$i];
$id_subseccion = $_POST['id_subseccion'][$i];


$sql = "INSERT INTO articulos (
            num_articulo,
            nombre_articulo,
            contenido_articulo,
            id_ley,
            id_titulo,
            id_capitulo,
            id_seccion,
            id_subseccion
        )
        VALUES (
            '$num_articulo',
            '$nombre_articulo',
            '$contenido_articulo',
            '$id_ley',
            '$id_titulo',
            '$id_capitulo',
            '$id_seccion',
            '$id_subseccion'
        )";

$res = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
}
echo json_encode($resultado);
?>
```

Si en el ajax comento esas lineas, console log me muestra esto:

```
11:56:11.685 Uncaught TypeError: 'append' called on an object that does not implement interface FormData. 
jQuery 4
myFunction linea:156
onclick linea:1
jquery-3.7.0.js:8762:5

POST [HTTP/2 500 Internal Server Error 69ms]
```

Pero no me muestra en consola "Error al enviar la consulta"

Y si no las comento, sí que aparece en consolo "Error al enviar la consulta".

En ambos casos el array data se muestra en consola asi:

```
Array [ "num_articulo[]", "5" ] nuevo_articulo.php:154:13 12:00:55.239
Array [ "nombre_articulo[]", "Representación." ]nuevo_articulo.php:154:13
12:00:55.239
Array [ "contenido_articulo[]", "1. Los interesados con capacidad de obrar podrán actuar por medio de representante, ......texto del articulo" ]
nuevo_articulo.php:154:13 12:00:55.239
Array [ "id_ley[]", "1" ] nuevo_articulo.php:154:13 12:00:55.239
Array [ "id_titulo[]", "1" ] nuevo_articulo.php:154:13 12:00:55.239
Array [ "id_capitulo[]", " " ] nuevo_articulo.php:154:13 12:00:55.240
Array [ "id_seccion[]", " " ] nuevo_articulo.php:154:13 12:00:55.240
Array [ "id_subseccion[]", " " ]nuevo_articulo.php:154:13 12:00:55.240
```

EL error 500 sigue ocurriendo en el servidor.
Ya perdonareis mi torpeza.

Comment: Añade los siguientes pares atributo-valor en el cuerpo del método `$.ajax()`: 

```processData: false,
contentType: false,```.

Existe una restricción [en la documentación](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) para el envío de datos en otros formatos que no sean de tipo *string*, por lo que es necesario establecer esos parámetros para enviar datos mediante el objeto `FormData`.

Comment: Si persistiera el error 500, en el archivo PHP añade estas dos líneas al principio del código: `var_dump($_POST); exit;`. Esto servirá para ver qué se está recibiendo del lado del servidor y así poder ver la forma de darle una solución al problema.

Comment: mil gracias Alexis, lo pruebo y comento

Comment: Me indica array(0) { }

Comment: Eso quiere decir que no estás recibiendo los datos. Por esa razón es que se produce el error, porque intentas procesar datos inexistentes. ¿Modificaste el cuerpo del método `$.ajax()`? Sería de ayuda que mostraras tu código actualizado. Puedes editar tu última publicación para añadir el código con los cambios hechos.

Comment: He editado mi última publicación para explicar mejor lo que previamente te comenté. Revísalo y prueba.